# Strange problem in php with % inside sql command

Tags: php, sql

I have a php file that gets some arguments to pass them to sql command. The first one is this:

```
if (isset ($_GET['pedio'])){
   $pedio = " ` pedio ` LIKE '%" . $_GET['pedio'] . "%'";
}
```

With this form, the code is not running. The problem is "%'". If I remove % from "%'" then the code is running but it not what I want to take as expression. I tried:

```
$pedio = " `pedio` LIKE '%" . $_GET['pedio'] . chr(37) . "'";
```

but it didn't help. If i change chr(37) to chr(38) then the code is running but I have & in the end of the expression, not %. What is wrong with it? Any solutions?

EDIT:
my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['pedio'])) {
    $pedio = " pedio LIKE '%$pedio%'";
}

if (isset($_GET['instit_type'])) {
    if ($pedio != "") {
        $instit_type = " AND";
    }

    $instit_type.= " instit_type = '" . $_GET['instit_type'] . "'";
}

if (isset($_GET['city'])) {
    if ($pedio != "" || $instit_type != "") {
        $city = " AND";
    }

    $city.= " city = '" . $_GET['city'] . "'";
}

echo "<p>" . $pedio . " , " . $instit_type . " , " . $city . "</p>";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE"; . $pedio;

// . $instit_type . $city . $category;
// echo $sql; $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

This modification is not working either:

```
if (isset ($_GET['pedio']))
{
    switch ($_GET['pedio']){
        case 1:
        $pedio = " `pedio` LIKE '%1%'";
        case 2:
        $pedio = " `pedio` LIKE '%2%'";
        case 3:
        $pedio = " `pedio` LIKE '%3%'";
        case 4:
        $pedio = " `pedio` LIKE '%4%'";
    }
}
```

Now, I noticed that

```
$pedio = " `pedio` = '%1%'";
```

code is running with no problem but the sql command is wrong and no results are returned. Replacing LIKE with = eliminates my problem? How is this possible? What is going on anyway?

Comment: Hello @JohnStergiou, can you share more code? ```$pedio = " pedio LIKE '%" . $_GET['pedio'] . "%'";``` isnt a correct SQL syntax.

Comment: No, it is not but this is a small part that creates the first expresion after  "WHERE". "Pedio" in my base is CHAR(5) and I have to look for a specific char inside. For example, I may need to look for 'a' inside 'abcd'. That's why I need " pedio LIKE '%a%' " to search. The second % is preventing my code from running. If I remove it the code runs fine. I also pasted all my php code to https://phpcodechecker.com and finds no problem.

Comment: Whats pedio? In mysql you need to [specific where to select from](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)... right now your SQL Query looks like ```pedio LIKE '%abc%'``` which isnt correct.

Comment: Pedio is the name of a column in the sql base. My query is: $sql = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE" . $pedio . ....other parameters....; Then I pass it to the caller.

Comment: User may need to add any search criteria in the sql query. That's why I check if the user passes value for column 'pedio'. If yes, then I pass the value for searching in the query using 'LIKE' instead of '='.

Comment: Something, somewhere deletes your %, more code please :-)

Comment: See more code in my comment below.

Comment: What have you tried to spot the error? Usually, most SQL connectors return an error message if something goes wrong

Comment: I just tried to paste all my code to phpcodechecker.com and said there is no error. JCH77 said that something deletes the last %. Hard to believe as if I use chr(37) happens the same thing, code is not running, but if I change 37 to everything else, the new character is present. Has it something to do with modulo? A bug or whatever? How can I make the server tell me what is wrong?

Comment: Also, if I change "%'" to something like "\%'" then the code is running. Removing \ it is not running again.

Comment: Totally, I found that it is a server problem. I need to find a workaround as the provider cannot do much.

Answer (score 1):

Its worth an answer.

If your base Query starts with `$sql = "SELECT * FROM schools WHERE";`, you need to manipulate the current variable by adding a `.` before `=` [src](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

Full code example

**ATTENTION** This example isnt secure! Use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead.

```
<?php
$baseSql = "SELECT * FROM school";

if(isset($_GET['pedio'])) {
    $baseSql .= "WHERE pedio LIKE '%" . $_GET['pedio'] . "%'";
}
?>
```

Comment: Also, in prepared statements that you mention, They use '$dbh'. I know that it is database handle but is it '$conn' in my code or is it something else?

Comment: Something important: as you see, pedio, city and instit_type have grey background color as they are inside ``. I do not know why but my server needs it.

Comment: @JohnStergiou Do not post code in comments, just edit your question :) I'll do it now for you.

Comment: Any suggetions?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following :

```
$variable = $_GET['pedio'];
$pedio = "pedio LIKE '%$variable%'";
```

Comment: Please explain **why** one should try your code. What exactly have you changed, and why do you think that it solves the problem?

Comment: It seems that it is an expression problem. This could be the solution.

Comment: No, I did not. I am wondering... am I the only one having such a problem?

Comment: "code is not running" doesn't give us a clue where to search for the problem and its solution, can you add the error message returned by your sql connector ?